# How to make comments work for a post loaded per Ajax?

Tags: posts, comments, ajax

I am currently loading a single post using ajax. While the post loading works ok, I cannot get the comments to load. Here is my code:

My javascript to load the post:

```
<script>
$(".view_post").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    postid = $(this).attr("rel");
    $.ajax({
        url:"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:'action=posts_open&postid='+postid,
        success: function(html){
            $("#b_contentwrapper").empty();
            $("#b_contentwrapper").append(html);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The javascript goes through functions.php this way:

```
function implement_posts()
{
    //<?php
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'single' );
    die();
}
```

Now here is the code where I actually load my post content:

```
<?php
    $linkid = "p=".$_POST["postid"];
    $posti = new WP_Query($linkid);
    $posti->the_post();
    echo "Time: ";
    the_time('F jS, Y');
    echo "<br />";
    the_category(', ');
    echo "<br />";
    the_title();
    echo "<br />";
    the_content();
    echo "<br />";
    comment_form();
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (have_comments()) {
        echo "Comments ok";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No comments";
    }
    ?>
```

Now, even for posts having comments I am getting "No comments" displayed. Everything else works correctly. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: `$linkid = "p=".$_POST["postid"];` is not verry sql injection safe. although wordpess checks this you might wanna do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the Codex on the `have_comments` function:

> This function relies upon the global $wp_query object to be set - this is usually the case from within The Loop

The problem is that your ajax handler creates its own WP_Query object. Note that you are not calling `the_post()`, instead you are calling `$posti->the_post()`. Same logic applies to comments as well.

Try the following:

```
if ($posti->have_comments()) {
    echo "Comments ok";
}  else {
    echo "No comments";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On my opinion, it would be better to go with a JQuery `.load($[this].attr('href') '.div-with-content-and-comment');`

Than make sure you have a single.php that has the markup with the `class="div-with-content-and-comment"` you want to load via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source of [`have_comments()`](http://queryposts.com/function/have_comments/) - this check retrieves data from global `$wp_query` object, which is not used in your case.

So the first step would be to replace `have_comments()` check with `$posti->have_comments()`.